# Static global pointer to run-time object in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, static

I am working on an embedded project that uses [this](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/ILI9341_t3) hardware driver. I wrote a wrapper module (C++ as C, no objects) around this library to easily integrate it with my project. However, to make things simpler, I compiled my C wrapper code as C++  to side-step the issue of calling C++ from C.

Essentially what I tried to do was have an *init* function that initializes the driver code and keeps a static handle around for the other functions to use from within the same translation unit. I am by no means a C++ expert, but I am puzzled surrounding my current problem.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
static ILI9341_t3 *tft;

void display_init(void){
    ILI9341_t3 _tft = ILI9341_t3(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST, TFT_MOSI, TFT_SCLK, TFT_MISO);
    _tft.begin();
    _tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
    _tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_YELLOW);
    tft = &_tft; 
}


void display_clear(void){
    tft->fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
}
```

This code compiles without issue, but any interaction with the screen after *display_init* is fruitless. Is this usage undefined in C++? What might be causing the object to become ineffective after leaving the scope of the init function?

This code seems to work if I put the entire object initialization in a static context, but I am not convinced this is the best path to take.

Comment: Use `static ILI9341_t3 _tft  ...` at least.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Wow. I think my short-sightedness with C/C++ won over here. Of course the object is on the stack ..